# Need help with understanding Ｘ ことは Ｘ construction

Tags: grammar

I need some help with this grammar point ’ことは'.

The definition I have is "Indeed one does something alright, but ~"

> Verb / い adj ことは V2/ い2 adj　"話すことは”　”高いことは”

Examples:

> - 高【たか】かったことは高かった
> - 笑う【わらう】ことは笑うがおかしくない
> - 便利【べんり】なことは便利だが、高すぎる
> - 安い【やすい】ことは安いがたちがわるい

Why is the verb/adjective always written twice? It's confusing. I just can't seem to understand these example sentences.

Answer (score 4):

This construction is usually followed by が or けれど and means something like "yes, one does X **but**...". It conveys the meaning that there's a caveat - the statement is true but there's a condition/fact that modifies its meaning, softening it or negating to some extent. It's used to justify your actions ("Yes, it was expensive but I needed it (so I bought it)."), providing an opposing view in a soft way ("Yes, it's nice but it's too dark (so I won't buy it)."), etc.

Don't worry about the fact that the verb or adjective is repeated twice - it's just the way the structure is built.

Note that this structure also exist for な-adjectives: な-adj ことは な2-adjだ.

It's best to understand it based on examples.

> 高{たか}かったことは高{たか}かった。。。
> It was expensive but... *(I liked it so I bought it anyway)*

> 笑{わら}うことは笑{わら}うがおかしくない。
> *(Yes, )* I laughed but it wasn't really funny.

> 便利{べんり}なことは便利{べんり}だが、高{たか}すぎる。
> *(It's true)* It is convenient but it's too expensive.

> 安{やす}いことは安{やす}いがたちがわるい。
> *(You may think)* It is cheap but the quality is poor.

---

Reference

- "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 206. 「ことは」structure's explanation - translated as "indeed one does something alright, (but ~); indeed ~ (but ~); do ~ (but ~)".
- "A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar", page 205. 「ことは」structure is compared to 「～ないこともない」. It is stated that both structure are used to not give an unconditional statement. The former is used to answer affirmative questions, the latter negative questions.

Comment: The reduplication can be made to sound natural, even in English: "Expensive things are expensive, I'll grant, but that's too much!"

Comment: I would like to know it this structure is formal or is used in everyday life, and/or written/oral. Thanks. (by the way, do I have to edit the question and start a bounty) ?