# Why can に be put after a verb's plain form?

Tags: particle-に

I just noticed this line in the System Preferences app on OS X:

[image]

It says

> 変更するにはカギをクリックします。
>
> Click the lock to make changes

Here, に is put after a verb's plain form. I have never seen this kind of usage before. As far as I know, に is a 格助詞. And 格助詞 don't connect to verbs. They only connect to 体言, which I think does not include verbs.

So i searched online to see if this is a usage that I am not aware of. And I found [this](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/053.html). But that does not show any examples of this "verb plain form + に" usage.

It also says that

> 格助詞は、主に**名詞**について、その**名詞**と他の語（他の名詞、あるいは、述語としての動詞・形容詞）との意味関係を示します。
>
> 格助詞 is mainly put after a **noun** and shows the relationship between that **noun** and another noun, a verb used as a predicate or an adjective.

How can に be put after a verb's plain form? What is this usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked say a 格助詞 **mainly** attaches to a noun. And according to デジタル大辞泉, に is a 格助詞 which can safely follow a verb:

> #### [に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%AB/)
>
> ［**格助**］名詞、名詞に準じる語、**動詞の連用形・連体形**などに付く。
>
> ５ 動作・作用の目的を表す。「見舞い―行く」「迎え―行く」

I think you are already familiar with expressions like 食べに ("in order to eat") or 見に ("in order to see"), and these are the masu-stems of verbs followed by the 格助詞-に.

See also:

- [What is the meaning of 「読むには読んだ」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34564/5010)

---

By the way, this verb before に is actually in the 連体形 (attributive form), not in the 終止形 (dictionary form). 終止形 is, as the name suggests, for ending a clause/sentence as a predicate. On the other hand, 連体形 (despite its name) worked as a nominalized noun in archaic Japanese. We can still see the 連体形 of a verb used as a noun in proverbs. For example, [逃げるが勝ち](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1) = "Running is winning", [聞くは一時の恥](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%80%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E6%81%A5%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AC%E3%81%AF%E6%9C%AB%E4%BB%A3%E3%81%AE%E6%81%A5) = "Asking is a one-time shame".

Comment: "連体形 (despite its name) worked as a nominalized noun in archaic Japanese." So does that mean it does not work as a noun in modern Japanese?

Comment: Yes you usually have to use の/こと to nominalize a verb in modern Japanese. But verbs before に are still called 連体形.

Comment: @naruto これは「には」独特の用法だと思うんですが、驚くことに大辞泉には載ってないんですね…大辞林にはありました（には④） https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-592565

Answer (score 1):

> (1)変更するにはカギをクリックします。
>   (2)変更するためにはカギをクリックします。

Simply, the given sentence (1) is made of sentence (2) by omitting "ため".
This kind of abbreviation is very common.

"ためには" means "in order to."