dictionary verb form followed by に
I know that には can follow dictionary verb form but the に in this sentence doesn't seem the same as には to me but how can this に can follow a dictionary verb. It sounds ungrammatical:
過去を詮索するに決まっている。

See e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46936, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27935.
