# Understanding the use of だった in this sentece

Tags: grammar

> あの人はいい人はいい**だった**けれど頑固だったね

I think I understand that だった but Im not completly sure, is it implied that Its refering to 人? Can you say よかった instead?

Comment: いいだった should be a typo for いい**人**だった. And.. which だった is your question about? →「あの人はいい人はいい人**だった**けれど頑固**だった**ね」

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same, either it was a typo or that 人 was somehow implied in the いいだった. So it is grammatically incorrect? I edited my question so now you can see which one I meant

Comment: 「いいだった」 is grammatically incorrect. 「いい人はいい人だが...」<- Related, maybe: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15682/9831

Comment: I understood the grammar It was just a little typo in the exercises I was reading haha thank you anyways ^ ^