# What is the purpose of the redundant "いい人" in this example sentence

Tags: nuances

A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar has this example sentence:

> あの人はいい人はいい人だったけれど頑固だったね。
>   "He was indeed a good person, but he was stubborn, wasn't he?"

What is the purpose of the "いい人は"? It reads to me as redundant: "That person. A good person. Was a good person. although sure was stubborn, eh?."

Whether I leave it out or in Google Translate gives me the same translation with slightly different wording.

What is being emphasized by putting it in?

Comment: That looks a lot like a typo.  Also, **never** use Google Translate to try to understand nuance.  Google Translate has been known to change translations based on how many newlines come after the end of a paragraph.  It's just not trustworthy.

Comment: Perhaps it’s a typo but they also spelled it out in romaji.

Comment: I feel like I've seen いい人はいい人 before, but a native I asked said that だった coming after it sounds strange.

Comment: It seems a tautology...

Comment: Not a typo but it is an awkward combination of words. Something other than あの人 as the topic would probably feel much better.

Comment: Eiríkr, 今回はタイポじゃないですね・・・　以前にこんなのがありましたけど：　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68704/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15682/9831

Comment: If anyone was curious, this is example sentence (g) under the "koto wa ことは" entry in A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Repeating a word using は is a way to emphasize something. There are several patterns.

- `X + は + X + が/けど/けれど` works like "indeed ～ but ～" or "it's true that ～ but ～". X can be an adjective, a noun or a verb (usually used with に). See: [What is the meaning of 「読むには読んだ」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34564/5010) and [Need help with understanding Ｘ ことは Ｘ construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15682/5010)

  > - おいしいはおいしいけど、量が少ない。
  > - この問題は簡単は簡単ですけど、時間はかかります。
  > - 彼女は学生は学生ですが、すでに2つの会社の社長でもあります。
  > - すべて売るには売ったが、利益はほとんどなかった。
  > - 彼はいい人はいい人ですよ。
  >     He is a nice guy, well, at least. (sometimes けど/が and the following part may be omitted; this implies there is something negative untold)
- `N + は + N + だ/です` (N: noun) as a predicate works just like English "a rule is a rule", etc.

  > - たとえ理不尽でも、ルールはルールです。
  > - ミスはミスだ、認めて謝罪しよう。
  > - 駄目なものは駄目だ。
  >     No means no.
  > - 運がよかったが、勝ちは勝ちだ。
- By extension, `N + は + N + だ/です` (N: noun) sometimes means "N is different" or "N is an exception".

  > - 彼は彼ですし。 Well, he is not like us.
  > - (idiom) それはそれです。 That's another story.
  > - (idiom) これはこれ、それはそれ。 They are irrelevant.
- `N + は + N + で` (N: noun) means "in its own way".
  See: [What is the meaning of あいつはあいつで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21167/5010)

  > - これはこれでおいしい。
  > - 彼女は彼女であなたのことを心配しています。
  > - 今日も忙しかったが、明日は明日で忙しい。